# Choosing Windows Phone IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7.1

My web service returns some data. I want to cache it.

Do I use this and serialize it to a file?

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
```

Or do I use this and stick it into the Dictionary?

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings
```

Comment: Why in the world would someone down vote this. Is the answer too obvious? It's not a duplicate. Sheesh. COMMENT if you do that.

Comment: This [post][1] could be helpful 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810465/silverlight-windows-phone-7-using-static-class-for-storing-data/5811642#5811642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For caching data I would stick it in a file in `IsolatedStorage`.
It is a little more work, but you can write a simple enough wrapper around it.

It is conceivable that `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` will one day be synced between devices using SkyDrive, this is the direction Microsoft are taking with Windows 8. So you should stick to using it for it's purpose which is application based settings.